# Rails creates entry in table after failing to save because of associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a `rails` application with 3 models (Job, Order, Fulfillment). The relationship between the models is:

1. Order `has one` Job
2. Fulfillment `has many` Jobs

[image: Model relationship]

The Jobs table has the following Schema:

```
  create_table "jobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "type"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "order_id"
    t.integer "fulfillment_id"
  end
```

---

Lets say I have an Order `o` and a Fulfillment `f`

```
o.job = Job.create!(:order_id => o.id, :fulfillment_id => f.id)
```

This creates a job associated to `o` and `f`.

But if I try to execute the same statement again, I get an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved` error but there exists a new Job entry in the table.

The same error is seen if I try to create the Job via the following method:

```
o.create_job!(:fulfillment_id => f.id)
```

Stack Trace:

```
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Fulfillment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "fulfillments".* FROM "fulfillments" WHERE "fulfillments"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Job Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "jobs" ("created_at", "updated_at", "order_id", "fulfillment_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2018-07-23 06:27:33.519957"], ["updated_at", "2018-07-23 06:27:33.519957"], ["order_id", 4], ["fulfillment_id", 1]]
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.7ms)  rollback transaction
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):82
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (Failed to remove the existing associated job. The record failed to save after its foreign key was set to nil.)
```

---

Why is this possible? If the association is being breached, and the transaction has been rolled-back, the table entry should have been deleted?

When exactly is Rails checking for failing association? How do I rescue from this error without having to manually delete the incorrect entry in the table?

Comment: You are using the `create!`, which also stores a record when the transaction failed. use `create` instead.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue by the way. It seems strange that there are two sets of transactions. Can you post the entire controller code? Did you try this exact command in Rails console, is it also triggering multiple transactions?

Comment: @bo-oz Using `create` vs `create!` did not really create any difference here. I can still see new table entries. Yes this stack trace was generated through the rails console. This issues is reflective of an issue in a private codebase at work. To replicate the issue I created a new rails application with these 3 models and no controller code as such.

Comment: I haven't ever done it the way you have it set up where I explicitly declare all the ids manually. Do you get the same behavior if you let Rails handle the building? e.g. job = o.job.create!(fullfillment_id: f.id)?

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone `NoMethodError (undefined method 'create' for nil:NilClass)`. I can create a job via `f.jobs.create!` but not via `o.job.create!`

Comment: @Sinstein I was assuming you were defining `o` somewhere else. Does `o = Order.find(by_whatever)` then `o.job.create(...)` work?

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone Yes that works. I tried `o.create_job!(:fulfillment_id => f.id)` and that failed the 2nd time with the same error as in the question. But I can still see a Job was added to the table.

Comment: How are you getting a fulfillment_id before a job is created?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176548/discussion-between-sinstein-and-oneworkingheadphone).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happen due to your `has_one` associations.

will fail because it is trying to delete the original order, but that one can't
be deleted because there is a validation on job_id.

This is because prior to deleting, the foreign key of the target association is set to nil and a save operation is performed on the target.

Please refer https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17325